# keep img tag absolutly centered and keep ratio

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the problem:

I have a slider full width of the page, with centered content.
Here's a quick HTML mockup for you to understand:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">
         <img src="01.jpg">
         <div class="wrapper">
              <h1>01</h1>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
         <img src="02.jpg">
         <div class="wrapper">
              <h1>02</h1>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
         <img src="03.jpg">
         <div class="wrapper">
              <h1>03</h1>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I would like the img tag to be centered in the slider div, but fill it completely. I know you can do this if I use background-image, but here I must change the background image on each slide, hence why I'm trying with the img tag.

here is my css so far:

```
.slider {
    height:370px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: grey;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center
}

.slide img {
    height:370px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}

.slide .wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
}
```

With this solution, the image gets resized on window resize, i need it to stay fixed in the center and just show more if needed depending on screen size (hence why my images are 1920*370px)

here is a quick fiddle with the image resizing problem : 
http://jsfiddle.net/4wZkN/

Thanks in advance to any help.

Comment: can u simulate the same in jsfiddle

Comment: Are you using any slider plugin ?

Comment: Not any in paticular yet, seems easy to do with any content slider.

Comment: Hey buddy, you were suppose add the working code, which was causing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBveb/). I changed the img to be position:fixed and removed the width specification. This prevents a scroll bar and exposes more image if you resize the frame. Is that the effect you were after?

```
.slide img {
    height:370px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```